# BTCPay Server AspNetCore Antiforgery Token could not be decrypted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, btcpay-server

I am running BTCPay Server behind a nginx reverse proxy and get this error. I believe this is why lightning addresses are not working.

```plaintext
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery: An exception was thrown while deserializing the token.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {a909f4bc-4e70-44e3-9ca5-68f7c054f712} was not found in the key ring.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.GetCookieTokenDoesNotThrow(HttpContext httpContext)
```

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Are you persisting your data protection keys correctly?

Comment: I am not sure whether I am or not. I have not tinkered with the btcpayserver docker files since I installed it. How can I check if I am?

Comment: Wait, so this isn't your programming project? You're just using an off-the-shelf project? In that case you should probably contact the product's support team / raise an issue on their GitHub.

Comment: Anyway: the keys ASP.NET Core uses for data protection need to be saved somewhere. IIRC, by default then calling `services.AddDataProtection()` they'll be persisted locally. If you're hosting the project somewhere other than on a single server whose file system exists between reboots, then you need to provide an alternative place to store these keys. It's possible here that when you restart the Docker image, it starts with a blank slate (since it's effectively a new file system within Docker) and generates new keys as it no longer has the old ones. Wrong keys = failed decryption.

Comment: It's also the same situation if you were to host somewhere like Google's Cloud Run, AWS' Fargate, etc. or in a cluster with something like Kubernetes. Anyway, since you seem to be using an off-the-shelf product rather than building one yourself, I imagine they provide some way of persisting your keys, so you should check if you're doing this or not.

Comment: Yeah I imagine that is the problem. I just wonder where in the docker image are these settings or files. I have raised an issue on their Github. Thank you!